# Meteor publish subscribe with remote mongo returns empty data

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to use a MongoDB collection which is obtained via subscription on the client side of Meteor. Besides that, on the server side the published collection must be obtained from a remote server. The code was adapted from one of the standard Meteor examples. Here is the server code:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  var sconn=  new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://user:passwd@192.168.155.116:27017/mydb");
  export const STasks= new Mongo.Collection("myCollection",{_driver: sconn});

  Meteor.publish('stasks', function stasksPublication() {
    return STasks.find({});
  });
});
```

And, on the client, I have

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

// >>>>> I suppose these two functions are irrelevant for the problem at hand, 
// >>>>> but I left just for sake of completeness.

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  // counter starts at 0
  this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  counter() {
    return Template.instance().counter.get();
  },
});

// >>>>> Here is where the problem happens: 

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    // increment the counter when button is clicked
    instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
    // My code to access data:        
    var  STasks=new Mongo.Collection("myCollection");
    Meteor.subscribe('stasks');
    console.log('Testing data');
    console.log(STasks.find().fetch());
  },
});
```

But all I get on the client console is an empty '[ ]'. I verified that on the server there is no problem to access the documents in myCollection.

Comment: i don't know anything about remote db's, but in your click handler, you're doing a find() immediately after subscribe(). that's a race condition. does your data appear if you click twice, after a pause?

Comment: I did this but no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';

var STasks=new Mongo.Collection("myCollection");

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
  // ...
  this.subscribe('stasks');
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  // ...
});

Template.hello.events({
  'click button'(event, instance) {
    // ...
    console.log(STasks.find().fetch());
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not change the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: on the publish side, use the `limit` parameter of the `find` function.

```
Meteor.publish('stasks', function stasksPublication() {
   return STasks.find({},{limit:5});
});
```

It seems rather peculiar, but I have an explanation for this: `myCollection` is really huge, with circa 500K rows. Instead of raising an error, the resulting behavior is showing empty brackets.